# Why Rails 4.1 cookie session serializer converts nested session keys from symbols to strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My old application happens to use nested session keys like this:

```
session[:nested] = {some_id: 123}
```

This worked nicely in Rails version 4.0 and older, but with Rails 4.1 it is broken: **nested session keys are de-serialized as strings**, so I no longer can reference those nested values by a symbol as follows:

```
session[:nested][:some_id]
```

However, top-level session keys still work fine:

```
# First action that puts values into session.
def set_session_vars
  session[:some_id] = 321
  session[:nested] = {some_id: 123}
end

# Second action that loads values from session.
def set_session_vars
  root_id = session[:some_id] # => 321, works as expected.
  nested_id = session[:nested][:some_id] # => nil, THIS DOES NOT!
end
```

I understand that Rails 4.1 brings a rather significant change to the way session is serialized - it no longer uses Marshal.dump, instead it uses basic JSON serializer which doesn't serialize objects as is. It should however work fine for basic types like integers and strings which I use.

I tried using a "hybrid" session serializer, but that doesn't work either:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```

**Question:** what can you recommend besides "don't use nested session keys"?

Thank you,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with same problem. I know this isn't the answer which you want, but it works.

`nested_id = session[:nested]['some_id'] # => 321`

**EDIT**

After all, I changed `:cookie_store` to `:active_record_store` at `config\initializers\session_store.rb`

You don't need to change other code.

`nested_id = session[:nested][:some_id] # => 321`

Comment: Thanks @mitsu. I already found the workaround for this problem.